# override function onclick button JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have Input text and button save. This is elements generate server. And I want override function, which call button save. This is part of my HTML code:

```
Phone: < input type = "text"
name = "Phone"
title = "title1"
value = "(999) 999-9999" > < input class = "ms-ButtonHeightWidth"
type = "button"
target = "_self"
accesskey = "O"
onclick = "if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("
ctl00$ctl19$g_491cf573_1d26_479b_ba3e_73aecb248dcb$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem ", "
", true, "
", "
", false, true))"
value = "Save" >
```

Can you help me write the function on JQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var buttonSave = $('[value="Save"]');
    var tempOnClick = buttinSave.Onclick;
    buttinSave.Onclick = Validate();

    function Validate() {
        if ($('[title="title1"]').text.lenght == 14) {
            tempOnClick.click();
        } else {
            alert("The field not valid!");
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I whant, when user click button save, call my function **Validate** And if input textbox has 14 symbol call default fucntion. It's possible?

Comment: So many mistakes you have , dude , cmon :D `buttin` instead of `button` , `lenght` instead of `length` See my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = $('input[value=Save]').click;
$('input[value=Save]').click(Validate);

function Validate() {
    if ($('input[title=title1]').val().length != 14) {
        alert("The field not valid!");
    }else {
        temp();
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dLnM3/1/)

Also, check naming of variables when you code! :) Good Luck!